# Words with double letters claimed to be used by Zamenhof but not found in Tekstaro in his texts

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, pronunciation

So there are two words that PIV claims they were used by Zamenhof: *nett/* (for **net** in "net weight") and *ghett/* (ghetto), which **doesn't sound like an Esperanto word at all** due to the *gh* beginning. Searching those two in Tekstaro gives only false positives, but there's one text that uses *ghetto* saying it was the "[Zamenhofa literumo]". So are those two words made up by PIV or are they attested in any of Zamenhof's texts?
(Same issue with the word *Buddo*)

Comment: What makes you claim that _ghett·o_ is "absolutely unpronounceable"? Depending on one's mother tongue, it might indeed be difficult to pronounce, but it shouldn't be impossible for everyone. I think I can pronounce it just fine (IPA: [ɡʱetˈto]), even though it doesn't really sound like a typical Esperanto word when pronounced.

Comment: @das-g nu, mi metaforumis tie, ĝi ne estas "neprononcebla", mi diras ĉar ĝia formo estas tute ne-Esperanta pro la pozicio de la h

Comment: @das-g The *h* in *ghetto* does not mark an aspirated consonant as in e.g. Hindi; it's the Italian convention to protect a hard velar from being palatalized by a following front vowel (as in *violoncello*).

Comment: In Italian (and probably also in English) that might be @AntonSherwood, but in Esperanto every word is pronounced exactly as written and every Esperanto letter is supposed to always represent the same sound/phoneme, independent of what word it occurs in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laŭ la Zamenhof-radikaro de Eugen Wüster (1927), la vorto *nette* aperas en la vortaro  *Wörterbuch Deutsch-Esperanto* de Zamenhof/Jürgensen, unua eldono (eble ĉ. 1904), kaj *Buddo* en Plena Vortaro Esperanta-Rusa (1909). En vortaroj troveblas ankaŭ *brutte*. Estas donita neniu teksto, en kiu Z vere uzis la vortojn. – Por *ghetto* mi trovis neniun fonton.

Vortaroj estas iom suspektindaj fontoj por aserti, ke vorto estas vere Zamenhofa, se li ne uzis ĝin en reala kunteksto. Cetere, ekzemple, la menciita Germana-Esperanta vortaro havas ankaŭ alian aŭtoron, kaj, kvankam oni diras, ke la teksto estis aprobita de Z, ekzistas certa dubo pri lia vera opinio pri tiuj formoj.

Zamenhof uzis plurfoje vortojn kun duoblaj konsonantoj, precipe tt kaj nn, do li ne principe kontraŭis tiajn.

Comment: Dankon! Sed mi vidas ke vortoj kun duoblaj konsonantoj apenaŭ ekzistas, ili estas uzataj por distingi disde alia vorto: finno vs. fino, bruto vs. brutta, neta vs. netta, budo vs. Buddo. Mi serĉis "villo" en Tekstaro kaj trovis nenion, eble estas neatestata formo de la vortaroj. Iel ajn, laŭ mi pli bonas Budao ol Buddo. Kaj kio pri _regatto_? Evidente estas por distingi el _regato_ (de _regi_), sed mi ankaŭ trovis neniun ateston.

Comment: La Tekstaro enhavas nur etan parton de ĉiuj skribaĵoj de Zamenhof. Estas neniel mirinde, ke ekz. _villo_ aŭ _regatto_ ne estas troveblaj. La Z-tekstoj kun tiuj vortoj ankoraŭ ne estas registritaj en la Tekstaro – eble ili iam estos.